# Дизайнер форм (VS 2010, Windows 10)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Добрый день!

Проблема в отображении элементов управления в дизайнер форм (VS 2010, Windows 10).
В студии отображается одно (т.е. отступы/положения элементов и т.д.), а в рантайме уже по другому.
Из-за этого сложно что-то лепить на форме, приходится запускать программу, смотреть в рантайме и потом поправлять в дизайнере.

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S.
В системе все оформление (размер шрифтов и тд.) штатное, ничего не менял.

***UPDATE 1***

[Штатные контролы отображаются нормально, разница только в размерах окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585327/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-vs-2010-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment782055_585327):
[image]

Comment: дизайнер _каких_ форм? winforms? wpf? еще каких-нибудь? какие именно элементы отличаются?

Comment: Да, сорри, WinForms.

Comment: Использую контролы от DevExpress. NavBar, в нем TextBox`ы и т.д.

Comment: отличаются именно DevExpress контролы? если их заменить на обычные - все становится нормально?

Comment: Не эксперементировал

Comment: Стоит попробовать и результаты в вопрос добавить

Comment: размер окна, кстати, тоже остался - разница в бордере только.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось банально простым.

По умолчанию у формы выставлен шрифт **Tahoma, 9.75**, просто изменил размер шрифта на **10**-ку и все встало на свои места.